# Cassandra Spring mvc - how to pass value

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

I try this and work fine.

```
@Autowired

private CassandraOperations cassandraOperations;

in my method
{
  String cqlAll = "select * from customer where cust_id=123";

  List<Customer> results = cassandraOperations.select(cqlAll, Customer.class);  
  for (Customer p : results) 
  {
    System.out.println(p.getCust_id() + "-"+p.getCust_name()+"-"+p.getCust_password());
  }
}
```

but I want to pass value to string so I can write my query file separately.
something like this,

```
String cqlAll = "select * from customer where cust_id=?";

objects[] obj = {123};

List<Customer> results = cassandraOperations.select(cqlAll, obj ,Customer.class);

for (Customer p : results) 
{
System.out.println(p.getCust_id() + "-"+p.getCust_name()+"-"+
  p.getCust_password());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CassandraOperation` select method can be build also with `com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Select`, as I can see from [spring data cassandra documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/CassandraOperations.html).

I do not have much experience with spring data cassandra, since we work directly with datastax java driver, but this should work for **select**:

```
final Select select = QueryBuilder.select().all().from("customer")
            .where(QueryBuilder.eq("cust_id", 123)).limit(200);
cassandraOperations.select(select ,Customer.class);
```

`123` can be any dynamic value pulled from object.

**Update** can be done using CqlOperations:

```
CqlOperations cqlOperations = new CqlOperations(); //or autowire it
final Statement update = QueryBuilder.update("customer")
                .with(QueryBuilder.set("email", "example@example.com"))
                .where(QueryBuilder.eq("cust_id", 123));
cqlOperations.execute(update);
```

Some more `QueryBuilder` examples can be found [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/reference/queryBuilder_r.html).

Comment: heyy @Nenad thanks for reply...

then for update, do I need to use Update update = QueryBuilder..... etc?

can you show update example please...

Comment: As for update I do not see method in CassandraOperations that accepts Update statement, everything is done with Entity so guess cannot be doen with QueryBuilder http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/CassandraOperations.html

Comment: It can be done it appears with CqlOperations so added example for that http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/cassandra/core/CqlOperations.html